# Magento Cron jobs /bin/bash: php7: command not found

Tags: php, linux, bash, magento, cron

I am new to Magento and am more used to scripting in PHP than doing Linux commands.

I tried setting up Cron Jobs for Magento as outlined here `https://www.properhost.com/support/kb/41/How-to-Configure-Magento-2-Cron-Jobs` but am getting an error email saying `/bin/bash: php7: command not found`

Ifound other articles that were leaving the version of PHP out of the command so it would be something like `php -f /home/<username>/public_html/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /home/<username>/public_html/var/log/magento.cron.log`, this is not emailing me any errors so thought I might have gotten somewhere but my site is still not reindexing.

Any ideas what I should do in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Try to change **php7** to **php7.0** in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the following in the log files `bin/magento must be run as a CLI application` so changed the command to php-cli and it seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `php` with its path `which php` worked for me.

```
/usr/local/bin/php -f /home/<username>/public_html/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /home/<username>/public_html/var/log/magento.cron.log
```